# a show-stopping bow-shaped train

Tags: word-meaning

> "I May Destroy You" creator and star Michaela Coel also shone bright in neon yellow. Her two-piece Christopher John Rogers design highlighted her toned tummy and had **a show-stopping bow-shaped train**.
> Source: USAToday    [The red carpet returned with a dose of glamour. See the 10 best dressed at the 2021 Emmys](https://www.usatoday.com/story/entertainment/celebrities/2021/09/19/emmys-2021-best-dressed-jason-sudeikis-kaley-cuoco-and-yara-shahidi/8413495002/)

What does "train" mean here? Does it mean "proper order"?

Comment: Her dress had an eye-catching (metaphorically exaggerated "show-stopping") [***train***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Train_(clothing)) that was shaped like a bow. But offhand I have no idea what "shaped like a bow" means here. I'd need to see a picture.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - 

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: I've never seen a dress train actually ***tied*** in a bow like that! Isn't it more likely the train is shaped like an archer's bow, or an ox-bow lake (i.e. - an ***arc***, not a complex decorative knot).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *train* of a dress is part that trails along the floor behind the wearer.

[Train (clothing)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Train_(clothing))

[image]

[image]

[image]